# If the database contains multiple exactly matching records, how to preserve only only one record, and delete rest duplicate of all records?

Tags: mysql, database

Consider their id is also same. Then how to preserve only one record, and delete rest duplicate of all records?

```
+-------+--------+--------+-------+
| empid | name   | salary | dept  |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+
|   100 | danial |  12000 | civil |
|   101 | giri   |   7000 | comp  |
|   100 | danial |  12000 | civil |
|   101 | giri   |   7000 | comp  |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Here I want to delete one danial or giri and another one should not be deleted how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Follow the duplicate link for a list of several methods you can use. Pick the one which works best for your data/situation.